# Apache and MySQL require restart every time I start XAMPP on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: lamp, xampp

Every time I launch the XAMPP(LAMPP) GUI in Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, I am unable to start the MySQL and Apache Web Server components; only ProFTPD.

The working solution I have found is to first run the following commands:

`sudo apachectl stop`

`sudo service mysql stop`

After that, if I click Start All in the GUI again they will both come online.

I'm not sure how to diagnose this problem; I am fairly new to adopting Linux.

I wanted to explore the idea of simply adding these commands to a .desktop file, to run after the GUI is launched, assuming it would operate in the same way a .bat file does in Windows.

This approach failed however. From what I have read, it seems as though .desktop files are not in vogue, and are frustrating to setup, particularly if they require sudo permissions to run, which I believe this XAMPP GUI does; it is launched with the following terminal command:

`sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run`

There was some deprecated suggestions online to use `gksu` in place of sudo in this .desktop file, the alternative now being `pkexec`, but this method also seemed to fail. I suspect I simply don't quite understand these .desktop files, and the whole approach is a blind alley, and probably there is a better way to solve the root issue anyway. I hope.

I suppose I could try to work out if these services(?) are running from boot. With htop, I have found some PIDs. but strangely not for Apache.

`PID 27441 ProFTPD`

`PID 31647 mysqld_safe`

I'm out of my depth.

Comment: Hi and welcome. First let me say I am not an expert writing Bash scripts but that is what you need. Maybe look into that.